# Cannot bind view programmatically in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, .net, caliburn.micro

I checked out the following thread and followed the example to try and bind a view dynamically:
[Caliburn.Micro: Create and Bind View programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333032/caliburn-micro-create-and-bind-view-programmatically)

My main view has a DataGrid with the following XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridTestSuites" Grid.Row="1" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12"
      IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      ItemsSource="{Binding TestSuites}"
      RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
      cal:Message.Attach="[Event RowDetailsVisibilityChanged] = [Action PopulateTestSuiteDetail($this, $eventArgs)]">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Binding="{Binding Category}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Assembly" Binding="{Binding AssemblyPath}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelTestSuiteDetail" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Note the StackPanel in the DataTemplate. This is where I want to inject my sub-view.

My view model has a function named PopulateTestSuiteDetails() which is attached to the RowDetailsVisibilityChanged event as described in the XAML:

```
public void PopulateTestSuiteDetail(DataModels.TestSuite testSuite, object eventArgs)
{
    if (!(eventArgs is DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs)) return;

    StackPanel stackPanel = (StackPanel)((DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs)eventArgs).DetailsElement.FindName("StackPanelTestSuiteDetail");

    var methodViewModel = IoC.Get<TestSuiteHelperMethodViewModel>();

    var methodView = new Harness.Views.TestSuiteHelperMethodView();

    stackPanel.Children.Add(methodView);
    ViewModelBinder.Bind(methodViewModel, methodView, null);
}
```

The function does get invoked correctly when I debug my program. However, it doesn't seem like my sub-view is being attached properly (my sub-view has a basic button and it is not visible when a data grid row is in focus.) Any idea why?

Comment: Instead of using StackPanel, I also tried using ContentControl with the name ActiveTestSuiteDetail. I have the same property in my view model. However, it doesn't seem like it is attaching the view properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I have to do the following to set my view and view model.

```
contentControl.Content = methodView;
Caliburn.Micro.View.SetModel(methodView, methodViewModel);
```

Comment: Where do you have to do this?